# Why can't you go outside after midnight?

Tags: atma

My pundit has told me several times that I cannot go outside after midnight because of bad spirits. What does he mean by this? Is this mentioned in the scriptures or is it just superstition? And what are bad spirits?

Comment: "Is this mentioned in the scriptures or is it just superstition?" - meaning, if something is mentioned in scriptures, it cannot be superstition?

Comment: @sv. Yes you are right both can be true.

Comment: @sv, superstition is just a name given to things people don't understand the reason for. "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic" - Arthur Clarke. People who say these things are superstitious are not at fault, they are simply at the lower rung of the knowledge ladder. One day they will rise higher and see the meaning behind them.

Comment: different beings have different levels of strengths at different times. during Brahma Muhurta, humans have strength. during day time, devas. during night time, asuras/pisachas/rakshasas, and ghosts that are doomed to roam the earth. These are the 'bad spirits'. They can mentally affect those who are not spiritually strong.

Comment: @ram how can they mentally effect humans? Also, how can you notice this?

Comment: @Wikash_, we don't question the cause of most of the ills that plague society today.. for e.g. what causes mental illness, depression, uncontrollable rage, sex addiction, perversion etc.. we just ignore them, or take medication to control them. but what actually causes them, and what can we do to prevent them ? for e.g. there is the concept of drushti dosham (evil eye), which is basically someone else feeling jealous about your beauty/wealth/status whatever, and sincerely wishing ill-will upon you. If they have spiritual power, their mental hatred towards u can manifest physically even without

Comment: them actually acting upon it. for e.g., you may trip and get injured, or get delayed in traffic during important meeting etc. we normally chalk it up to 'random' chance, or coincidence, which is simply an unscientific make-up for "i don't know why, but i'm too proud to say so, and too lazy to search for answers, and too adamant to believe old traditions, so hiding behind the disguise of science, i will just call it random, and look intelligent". there is always a cause if you look deeper.

Comment: @ram how is the evil eye related to the bad spirits? The pundit told me that people can get evil eyes if they are jealous of something but what do bad spirits have to do with this?

Comment: @Wikash_, i was just giving an example of something that can affect us, but it's deemed as superstitious by 'scientific' people who have arbitrarily drawn the boundary line of science. evil spirits can affect us in the same way evil eyes of living people can affect us. they can put pressure on our mental state in a way that will make us do things we won't normally do when in full control of our faculties.

Comment: @ram do these bad sprits arise specifically after midnight? Or when it is dark outside?

Comment: @Wikash_, generally, their strength increases after sun goes down, and reduces after it comes up. that's why almost no vedic rituals are sanctioned after sundown. unless you're in Andhra Pradesh, where they follow Chandramana calendar, so even weddings happen at night. As long as you follow what **your** parents, acharya or purohit tell you, you will be protected. People always looking for a universal objective rule that applies to everyone, which is very childish.

Comment: @ram are those bad spirits jiva atma's who have turned bad?

Comment: @Wikash_, that's a circular question.. of course bad spirits are bad. whether asura, rakshasa, pisacha, preta, deva, manushya, ant, lion, brahma - all are jivatmas.. jivatma itself doesn't TURN good or bad, because good & bad are not permanent qualifications of jiva. if a jiva's punya credit is higher, it's called good. if papa credit is higher, it's called bad. it can earn or spend punya or papa and its balance will change accordingly.

Comment: @Manu Kumar why can't these spirits bear the sunlight?

Comment: Evil spirits are said to reside in antariksha during sunlight, when they're helpless can't come down to earth, some research says there are infinite no of microbes on venus atmosphere(antariksha, space between earth and its neighbour planet venus), as well as even shukracharya (venus) is guru of Asuras, evil spirits.